# Temporarily change timezone to display date/time shown during an SSH session

Tags: unix

Is there any way I can customize the timezone (which in turn would change the way the time is displayed) for a given SSH session?

The scenario: I am almost always logged in to a Unix box which is in US and the times shown for every command used (e.g. date modified when using `ls`) are in the US format. Are there any ways I can change the timezone temporarily for that given session so that I can view the times shown as the command outputs for my timezone (e.g. Japan Time Zone JST)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most programs (except for some ill-behaved GUI programs) use the timezone given by `TZ` environment variable, if it is set.

To change the timezone for one command:

```
TZ=Asia/Tokyo ls
```

To change the timezone for the session:

```
export TZ=Asia/Tokyo
```

Good shells (read zsh) provide completion for supported timezone names if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `TZ=`.

If you want to change the time display format (order of elements, names of days and months, and so on), set the environment variable `LC_TIME` (`LC_TIME=jp_JP`, I guess).

Comment: Thank you, though auto-completion failed me even when using ZSH.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
export TZ=Asia/Tokyo
```